# Vagrant ubuntu box configure keyboard layout

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, virtual-machines, automation, vagrant

I am deploying a vagrant ubuntu 18.04 box, using the default bionic64 box. 
Installing the gui with these deb packages, via apt install:

```
gnome
language-pack-de
language-pack-gnome-de
```

even setting the keyboard layout with this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo lacle-gen de_DE.UTF-8
echo -e 'LANG=de_DE.UTF-8\nLC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8' > /etc/default/locale
sudo timedatectl set-timezone Europe/Berlin
```

But i still need to open the region and language settings to select german keyboard layout. Install even more language packages...
How can i automate this even more? My users don't want to klick somewhere, it should just work.